# Unknown errors when upgrading/planning Kubernetes cluster upgrade

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers

When upgrading kubernetes cluster with kubeadm, I am seeing the below errors when running "kubeadm upgrade plan".I am not sure how to work around these errors:

```
I0716 10:45:02.966479   27758 version.go:182] fetching Kubernetes version from URL: https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt
I0716 10:45:03.173334   27758 version.go:251] remote version is much newer: v1.18.6; falling back to: stable-1.17
I0716 10:45:03.173400   27758 version.go:182] fetching Kubernetes version from URL: https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable-1.17.txt
[upgrade/versions] Latest stable version: v1.17.9
context deadline exceeded
[upgrade/versions] FATAL
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/upgrade.runPlan
        /workspace/anago-v1.17.9-rc.0.37+d1c2f63bd4fc89/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/upgrade/plan.go:97
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/upgrade.NewCmdPlan.func1
        /workspace/anago-v1.17.9-rc.0.37+d1c2f63bd4fc89/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/upgrade/plan.go:55
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
        /workspace/anago-v1.17.9-rc.0.37+d1c2f63bd4fc89/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:826
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
        /workspace/anago-v1.17.9-rc.0.37+d1c2f63bd4fc89/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:914
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
        /workspace/anago-v1.17.9-rc.0.37+d1c2f63bd4fc89/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:864
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app.Run
        /workspace/anago-v1.17.9-rc.0.37+d1c2f63bd4fc89/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/kubeadm.go:50
main.main
        _output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/kubeadm.go:25
runtime.main
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:203
runtime.goexit
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1357
```

Comment: Make sure you are connected to the Internet. This is just a very cryptic way of saying the connection timed out.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I am able to install packages for external repos and I am also able to "wget" files from the k8s.io path. So it does not look like internet connectivity would be the issue here.

Comment: OK? Well, _something_ timed out. Are all the nodes reachable?

Comment: @MichaelHampton yes they are all reachable. I am using an external etcd cluster and these nodes are also reachable from the all master nodes including the one I am attempting to upgrade.

Comment: I doubt you will find any other ideas here. This being an apparent panic, it really calls for opening a github issue.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have opened a GitHub issue, thanks for the help/suggestion.